# improve speed of mysql import

Tags: mysql, linux, database-administration

I have large database of `22GB`. I used to take backup with `mysqldump` command in a gzip format.

When i extract the gz file it produces the `.sql` file of `16.2GB`

When I try to import the database in my local server, it takes approximately 48hrs to import.Is there a way to increase the speed of the import process?

Also i would like to know if any hardware changes need to be done to improve the performance.

Current System Config

```
 Processor: 4th Gen i5
 RAM: 8GB
```

**#update**

my.cnf is as follows

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 512M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 4M
query_cache_size        = 512M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 512M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 512M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

It is being uploading for 3 days and right now 9.9 GB has been imported. The Database has both `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` tables. What can i do to improve the import performance?

I have tried exporting each table separately  in gz format with `mysqldump` and importing each table through PHP script executing the following code

```
$dir="./";
$files = scandir($dir, 1);
array_pop($files);
array_pop($files);
$tablecount=0;
foreach($files as $file){
    $tablecount++;
    echo $tablecount."     ";

    echo $file."\n";
    $command="gunzip < ".$file." | mysql -u root -pubuntu cms";

    echo exec($command);
}
```

Comment: Can you accept the mysql server to be down for a few seconds? If you can, then backup the mysql database files directly and just copy them back when restoring. Both the two operations requires the mysql server to be taken offline. It's an unsafe but efficient way.

Comment: how many tables do you have ?

Comment: You can add more information about the problem - is the bottleneck CPU or disk, is a specific table causing the slow import; if so, what is the structure of the table, how many rows are in it and etc.

Comment: @Alex I have 204 tables

Comment: We had some big tables (10GB) and for MySQL it was just too much for import / export. What helped was move big log tables to MongoDB. I know it's not going to solve your problem but one day you might need make a decision.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2167641/763468

Comment: You could also selectively dump tables.  If there are any log/cache tables that you don't need locally, exclude them from your `mysqldump`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs over at [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a lot of parameters that are missing, to fully understand the reason for the problem. such as:

1. MySQL version
2. Disk type and speed
3. Free memory on the server before you start MySQL server
4. iostat output before and at the time of the mysqldump.
5. What are the parameters that you use to create the dump file in the first place.

and many more.

So I'll try to guess that your problem is in the disks because I have 150 instances of MySQL that I manage with 3TB of data on one of them, and usually the disk is the problem

Now to the solution:

First of all - your MySQL is not configured for best performance.

You can read about the most important settings to configure at Percona blog post:
http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-settings-to-tune-after-installation/

Especially check the parameters:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size 
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
innodb_flush_method
```

If your problem is the disk - reading the file from the same drive - is making the problem worse.

And if your MySQL server starting to swap because it does not have enough RAM available - your problem becomes even bigger.

You need to run diagnostics on your machine before and at the time of the restore procedure to figure that out.

Furthermore, I can suggest you to use another technic to perform the rebuild task, which works faster than mysqldump.

It is Percona Xtrabackup - http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/

You will need to create the backup with it, and restore from it, or rebuild from running server directly with streaming option.

Also, MySQL version starting from 5.5 - InnoDB performs faster than MyISAM. Consider changing all your tables to it.

Comment: Will changing the tables to MyISAM to InnoDB affect any relation? or any damage to my DB? Is there any specific advantage to use MyISAM rather than using InnoDB?

Comment: If you will ask any of the MySQL experts - all of them will say - No. Today there is no advantage in using MyISAM over InnoDB. But you need to verify the code that uses your tables and make sure that it does not rely on table locks that MyISAM performs

Comment: The biggest problem with standard mysqldump and import isn't really that the hard disk is a bottleneck, the biggest problem is that when you are doing this you actually are inserting all the data into a table again rather than simply copying the data structure. So, you have to recreate the structure. It is a major software limitation that is exacerbated by slow disks. MyISAM has a very real advantage over Innodb when it comes to backups: you can simply lock and flush the tables and copy the data using cp or scp and it works fine (remember to chown mysql:mysql the files).

Comment: @ChrisSeline - you can do the same with InnoDB tables, but when you do this- your DB will not be functional. Don't try backing up a 1TB of data this way from a production DB.

Comment: Doing this with InnoDB is much more complicated. I have had some success copying over an entire db with InnoDB tables using scp, but never have I been successful with a single table. And you can still backup production data, you just can't write to the table while you do it :). Anyways, I am sure this is why the Percona tool exists, because it is a pain in the butt!

Answer (score 17):

Doing a dump and restore in the manner described will mean MySQL has to completely rebuild indexes as the data is imported. It also has to parse the data each time.

It would be much more efficient if you could copy data files in a format MySQL already understands. A good way of doing this is to use [innobackupex](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/creating_a_backup_ibk.html) from Percona

(Open Source and distributed as part of [XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup) available to download from [here](https://www.percona.com/downloads/XtraBackup/LATEST/)).

This will take a snapshot of MyISAM tables, and for InnoDB tables it will copy the underlying files, then replay the transaction log against them to ensure a consistent state. It can do this from a live server with no downtime (I have no idea if that is a requirement of yours?)

I suggest you read the documentation, but to take a backup in it's simplest form use:

```
$ innobackupex --user=DBUSER --password=DBUSERPASS /path/to/BACKUP-DIR/
$ innobackupex --apply-log /path/to/BACKUP-DIR/
```

If the data is on the same machine, then innobackupex even has a simple restore command:

```
$ innobackupex --copy-back /path/to/BACKUP-DIR
```

There are many more options and different ways of actually doing the backup so I would really encourage you have a good read of the documentation before you begin.

For reference to speed, our slow test server, which does about 600 IOPS can restore a 500 GB backup in about 4 hours using this method.

Lastly: You mentioned what could be done to speed up importing. It's mostly going to depend on what the bottle neck is. Typically, import operations are I/O bound (you can test this by checking for io waits) and the way to speed that up is with faster disk throughput - either faster disks themselves, or more of them in unison.

Answer (score 9):

One thing you can do is

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

And you can also play with the values

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
innodb_flush_method
```

in `my.cnf` to get you going but in general you should have a look at the [rest of innodb parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html) as well to see what best suits you.

This is a problem I have had in the past I don't feel I have tackled completely but I hope I had pointed myself in this direction from the get go. Would have saved myself quite some time.

Comment: currently the normal import is in progress. once it is done let me try this

Comment: setting innodb_buffe_pool_size in my.cnf doesnt start the mysql server

Comment: @DharanBro That's because you mis-spelt it.

Answer (score 7):

I had to import almost the same size dump as yours (15.8GB) and it took me 2.2 hours to complete using the following settings:

my.cnf:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_write_io_threads = 32
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_doublewrite = 0
```

My system specs are:

```
CPU: core i5 7th gen
RAM: 16GB
HDD: 500GB
```

I have configured those settings according to my system specs as your system has 8GB ram so you can configure it similar to this:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_doublewrite = 0
```

You can play around to see which configuration better suites you. Also don't forget to restart your mysql to apply the changes.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you increase your "**max_allowed_packet**" variable to a large enough size. This will really help if you have a lot of text data. Using high performance hardware will surely improve the speed of importing data.

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=256M -u root -p < "database-file.sql"
```

Comment: max_allowed_packet  = 512M is in the config, so making it 256M will actually decrease it's size.

Answer (score 3):

Way 1: Disable the foreign keys as fakedrake suggested.

SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0

Way 2: Use BigDump, it will chunk your mysqldump file and then import that.
http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/

Question: You said that you are uploading ? how you are importing your dump ? not directly from the server /command line?

Answer (score 3):

I've had to deal with the same issue.  I've found using `mysqldump` to output to a CSV file (like this):

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p -t -T/path/to/db/directory [database] --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,
```

and then importing that data using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` query from within the mysql client (like this):

```
LOAD DATA FROM INFILE /path/to/db/directory/table.csv INTO TABLE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

to be about an order of magnitude faster than just executing the SQL queries containing the data.  Of course, it's also dependent on the tables being already created (and empty).

You can of course do that as well by exporting and then importing your empty schema first.

Comment: One big caveat to using the `-T` option with msyqldump is that this only works if mysqldump is run on the same machine as the mysqld server.

Answer (score 2):

Get more RAM, get a faster processor, get an SSD for faster writes.  Batch the inserts so they will run faster than a bunch of individual inserts.  It's a huge file, and will take time.

Answer (score 1):

The method descirbed in [Vinbot's answer above][1] using `LOAD DATA INFILE` is how I bring in about 1 Gb every day for an analysis process on my local desktop (I don't have DBA or `CREATE TABLE`rights on the server, but I do on my local mySQL).

A new feature introduced in mySQL 8.0.17, the [mySQL Parallel Table Import Utility][2], takes it to the next level.

An import of CSV tables that formerly took about 15 minutes (approx 1 Gb) now takes 5:30, on an Intel Core I7-6820HQ with a SATA SSD.  When I added an nVME M.2 1Tb WD Black drive (bought for an old desktop but proved incompatible) and moved the mySQL installation to that drive, the time dropped to 4 min 15 sec.

I define most of my indexes in table definitions prior to running the utility.  THe loads are even faster without indexing, but post-load indexing ends up taking more total time.  This makes sense, as the multi-core feature of the Parallel Loader extends to index creation.

I also `ALTER INSTANCE DISABLE INNODB REDO_LOG` (introduced 8.0.21) in the parallel loader utility script.  Heed the warning not to leave this off after finished with the bulk load.  I did not reenable and ended up with corrupted instance (not just tables, but the whole instance).  I keep double-write buffering off, always.

The CPU monitor shows the utility fully utilizes all 8 cores.

Once done with the parallel loader, it's back to single-threaded mySQL (for my linear set of analysis tasks, not multi-user). The new nVME cuts times by 10% or so.   The utility saves me several minutes, every day.

The utility allows you to manage buffer sizes and number of threads.  I match the number of physical cores in my CPU (8) and that seems optimal.  (I originally came to this thread looking for optimization tips on configuring the parallel loader).
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29922299/5839677
[2]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-parallel-table.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its an option for you, but the best way to go about this is what Tata and AndySavage already said: to take a snapshot of the data files from the production server and then install them on your local box by using Percona's innobackupex. It will backup InnoDb tables in a consistent way and perform a write lock on MyISAM tables.

Prepare a full backup on the production machine:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/preparing_a_backup_ibk.html

Copy (or pipe via SSH while making the backup - more info [here](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/streaming_backups_innobackupex.html)) the backed up files to your local machine and restore them:

Restore the backup:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/restoring_a_backup_ibk.html

You can find the full documentation of innobackupex here: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html

The restoration time will be MUCH faster than reading an SQL dump.

Answer (score 0):

When your SQL file has 1 statement per line, you can import the file many times faster by having many INSERTS in one statement.

Example. Change:

```
INSERT INTO abc VALUES(1,2,3)
INSERT INTO abc VALUES(4,5,6)
INSERT INTO abc VALUES(4,5,6)
```

Into:

```
INSERT INTO abc VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Probably the last version has less commit; instructions.